# Can Oka's coherence theorem be made (partially) constructive / algorithmic?

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

It is a deep theorem due to Oka that the structure sheaf of holomorphic functions $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n}$ is coherent.

Is it (at least in principle) possible to program this result as an algorithm?  As an algorithm, this would correspond to specifying an open set $U$ and some holomorphic sections $s_1, \dots, s_n$ on that set and for the program to return a finite list of (holomorphic) relations that these sections satisfy.  Presumably we can't specify *any* holomorphic sections but we could perhaps restrict ourselves to ones that can be written in terms of polynomials and exponentials.

Are there known results related to this?